# Rewrite nginx redirect

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect a search url.

wrong url
https://casadeaustin.pe/advanced-search/?check_in=2022%2F12%2F14&check_out=2022-12-15&wpestate_regular_search_nonce=5163c60432&_wp_http_referer=%2F&submit=Search

Correct url (I need to replace the "%2F" with "-" in the url)
https://casadeaustin.pe/advanced-search/?check_in=2022-12-14&check_out=2022-12-15&wpestate_regular_search_nonce=5163c60432&_wp_http_referer=%2F&submit=Search

Uso nginx.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like the XY problem. Even with simple URLs, rewriting or redirecting the URL in a webserver shouldbe your VERY LAST resort after after changing the places where the wrong URL has been published.

Comment: BTW the "wrong" and "correct" URLs you've published here are the same.

Comment: They are not the same, you can see the error here.
check_in=2022%2F12%2F14
check_in=2022-12-14

Comment: true but what about the %2F before `&submit=Search`?

Comment: When I run the search, it breaks because the format is not correct.

Comment: Check my site https://casadeaustin.pe.
Try to do a search and look at the dates, you will see that at the beginning it shows a format and when you finish placing the dates the format changes. The problem is that on some mobile devices it does not change the format at the end and the search breaks.

Comment: You would need some `map` magic to rewrite the query arguments. However, you should fix the root cause, the application that is creating these invalid URLs in the first place.

Comment: Possible solution: `if ($args ~ (.*)%2F(\d+)%2F(.*)) { return 301 $uri?$1-$2-$3; }`